# Upgrade SSD / Windows 10

Tags: windows, ssd, upgrade, reinstall

I already have a SSD in my desktop PC but I'd like to upgrade to an m.2 drive with more storage space.

I've also been having quite a lot of issues with Windows recently (lots of BSOD and random glitches), so I think it would be best to perform a complete reinstall from scratch instead of transferring/cloning the data from my current SSD. (I can reinstall the programs later and all my other files are stored in a HDD so that's not really a problem).

I already have a Windows Home license with my current setup (it's a non-OEM version I think, the one that costs around $130 and that comes with an USB stick in a box).

My question is, would it be possible to remove my current SSD from my PC, replace it with the blank M.2 drive, plug the Windows installation USB stick and re-install Windows with the same license as if I was setting up the PC for the first time, or would Windows prevent me from doing this because the license has already been used previously? If that's possible, do I need to check anything in particular when setting up the OS?

Comment: It should work. Its also quite posisble that you can say skip at the setup when prompted for the s/n and that windows automatically activates because most of the hardware is still the same.

Comment: Yes, remove the original SSD, install m.2 drive, and then reinstall the operating system and use the original license to activate the operating system.